# How to disable font smoothing in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ide, xcode9

I've got a great programming font [Deccy](https://github.com/nazariyg/Deccy-font) that only looks good with font smoothing (anti aliasing) disabled in Xcode. With Xcode 8 the following would do the trick:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSFontDefaultScreenFontSubstitutionEnabled -bool YES
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 24
```

But this no longer works with Xcode 9.

Would it be possible to disable font smoothing in Xcode 9?

Comment: Which font is it?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions found here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268931/disable-antialiasing-inside-xcode I see you need to set 3 things, and you seem to be setting only 2.

Comment: @bbaassssiiee https://github.com/nazariyg/Deccy-font

Comment: @Pochi Yes, already tried that.

Comment: Did you tried `defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 4`

Comment: What happened with the bounty?

Comment: May be try disabling it in Xcode 9 GM or a stable version. Might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Mischief managed?

Here's a screenshot of my Xcode 9 with Deccy at 13pt:

[image: The text appears crisp, with no blurred edges.]

I believe the above is what you want. Here's stock Xcode displaying the same file:

[image: Though the font was designed with crisp pixel boundaries, it appears here, blurred, as if seen through the haze of one too many hours programming.]

### But how?

I probed deep for a noninvasive way to accomplish this, and failed. As far as I can tell, the text rendering path in Xcode 9 very deliberately turns on font smoothing.

> **Before going any further, please file a feature request with Apple. It only takes a few minutes, and it's your best hope for an answer that that can be discussed in front of those with sound security instincts and strained cardiovasculature:**
>
> https://bugreport.apple.com/

I wrote an Xcode plugin. You might have heard that Xcode 9 uses code signing restrictions to forbid the loading of plugins. This is true, but a few mavericks press on, and tonight we ride with them.

#### Step one

There is a tool, [update_xcode_plugins](https://github.com/inket/update_xcode_plugins). You can use it to strip the code signature from your copy of Xcode, and with it the bundle-loading restriction:

```
$ gem install update_xcode_plugins
$ update_xcode_plugins --unsign
```

If you change your mind, you can do this to revert to (a backup copy, I think?) of signed Xcode:

```
$ update_xcode_plugins --restore
```

#### Step two

There is another tool, [Alcatraz](https://github.com/alcatraz/Alcatraz/). It's a plugin manager for Xcode. I chose to install it because it provides a plugin which provides a project template for plugins. I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/alcatraz/Alcatraz/pull/488#issuecomment-333275108) to install Alcatraz, which boil down to this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/alcatraz/Alcatraz.git
$ cd Alcatraz
$ xcodebuild
```

I launched Xcode, clicked through the dialog warning me about the new plugin, and then used the newly-added Window > Package Manager to install the "Xcode Plugin" template.

### Step three

I made a project with this template.

As I write this, the "Xcode Plugin" template hasn't been updated to support Xcode 9. No worries. I ran this command to grab Xcode 9's compatibility UUID:

```
$ defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID
```

I visited my new project's Info.plist and added that UUID to the `DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs` array.

Then, I linked `SourceEditor.framework` into my project. That was a two-step process:

1. Visit the target's Build Settings. Add this to Framework Search Paths:

   ```
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/
   ```
2. Visit the target's Build Phases. Add a new "Link Binary With Libraries" phase. Hit the plus. Navigate to the directory above (you can just press the <kbd>/</kbd> key and then paste the path in) and choose `SourceEditor.framework`. It should appear in the list. The project should still build.

Then, I made my plugin's `.mm` file look like this (I deleted the `.h` file, it's unneeded for this PoC):

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

extern void CGContextSetAllowsFontAntialiasing(CGContextRef, BOOL);

static void hooked_sourceEditorSetFontSmoothingStyle(CGContextRef ctx) {
    CGContextSetAllowsFontAntialiasing(ctx, NO);
}

@interface NoAA : NSObject
@end

@implementation NoAA

+ (void)pluginDidLoad:(NSBundle *)plugin
{
    NSArray *allowedLoaders = [plugin objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"me.delisa.XcodePluginBase.AllowedLoaders"];
    if (![allowedLoaders containsObject:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]])
        return;

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"SourceEditorScrollView");
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:cls];
    void *handle = dlopen(bundle.executablePath.fileSystemRepresentation, RTLD_NOW);
    if (!handle)
        return;
    uint8_t* set_font_smoothing_fn = dlsym(handle, "sourceEditorSetFontSmoothingStyle");
    if (!set_font_smoothing_fn)
        goto fin;
    void* set_font_smoothing_fn_page = (void*)((long)set_font_smoothing_fn & -PAGE_SIZE);
    if (mprotect(set_font_smoothing_fn_page, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC))
        goto fin;
    set_font_smoothing_fn[0] = 0xe9; // jmp
    uint32_t* jmp_arg = (uint32_t*)(set_font_smoothing_fn + 1);
    *jmp_arg = (uint32_t)((long)hooked_sourceEditorSetFontSmoothingStyle - (long)(jmp_arg + 1));
    mprotect(set_font_smoothing_fn_page, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC);

fin:
    dlclose(handle);
}

@end
```

…I think the `goto`s add character. Basically, it just defines a function that takes a `CGContextRef` and turns off text antialiasing for it. Then, it overwrites the beginning of a function inside the SourceEditor framework which ordinarily configures antialiasing settings — don't need that anymore — to jump to our function instead. It does all of this in an incredibly unsafe way, so if something goes wrong, Xcode may politely crash.

Build and run the project, which automatically installs the plugin. Accept the addition of your plugin, and that's that.

### What now?

If anything here doesn't work because I messed up, let me know. I'm *not* planning to roll this into an Alcatraz plugin myself, but you or anyone else should free to do so with credit (after filing a feature request with Apple).

Happy hacking!

Comment: Couldn't find the Xcode Plugin template option in the New Project dialog after installing Alcatraz. I however was able to use this [plugin project](https://github.com/omz/Dash-Plugin-for-Xcode) as a template instead. And then it worked. Thank you.

Comment: After installing Alcatraz, launch it from Window -> Package Manager and install the template from the "Templates" tab. Then, it should show up all the way at the bottom of the macOS tab of the New Project window.

Comment: Deccy is best viewed at 12.5 though!

Comment: Hopefully you were able to choose that size somehow?

Comment: FYI With the kattrali/Xcode-Plugin-Template that installs from the "Templates" tab in the Package Manager you can't link any binaries or frameworks, the "Link Binary With Libraries" phase is missing.

Comment: That's true for the template I used too (see answer). I had to add that phase with the + at the top of the panel.

Comment: There's one little issue with this approach in Xcode 9: if you type "-" long enough you can see that the symbols are not spaced regularly. Text used to be spaced evenly in previous Xcode versions.

Comment: If the Alcatraz doesn't load after building, edit Alcatraz-Info.plist, add UUID for the XCode and rebuild, see https://github.com/alcatraz/Alcatraz/issues/498

Comment: Also in my case (XCode 9.2), I wasn't able to select `SourceEditor.framework`. I just did `ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ Xcode.frameworks` in my project directory and then clicked `Add other` from the framework selection dialog, then chose the linked directory and selected `SourceEditor.framework` from there. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

If you 'live' in XCode and need a crisp rendering of this TrueType font, then editing XCode application defaults with [PrefEdit.app](http://www.bresink.com/osx/PrefEdit.html), or `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode.*` has no effect.

[image: Default rendering]

Thinking outside the box you might be interested in the following to achieve crispyness all-over your Mac.

Since the Deccy font is best viewed at 12pt, it makes sense to raise the *AppleAntiAliasingThreshold* in the global domain to 13, the default for this setting is 4.
You can also suggest no *AppleFontSmoothing*.

`defaults write -g AppleFontSmoothing -int 0
   defaults write -g AppleAntiAliasingThreshold -int 13`

In addition to these tweaks a bit more can be achieved in the **Accessibility Preference** pane in System Preferences: The Display has 2 checkmarks that you should try: '**Differentiate without  color**', and '**Increase contrast**'.

[image: contrast rendering]

*"Beauty is in the eye of the beholder"*, **I hope this helps.**

Comment: Does your solution in fact works for Deccy and Xcode 9?

Comment: The screenshot is Deccy in XCode.

Comment: The letters on the screenshot don't seem to appear crisp

Comment: That is because the Caddy font is in an old format TrueType

Comment: It used to be crisp in Xcode 8, 7, and 6. Your answer is far from being of any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here are alternative steps that might work for you.

1. Try to find the com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist file under Macintosh HD/Library/Preferences.
2. Copy the file to desktop
3. Open file and add NSFontDefaultScreenFontSubstitutionEnabled to (Boolean)YES
4. add AppleAntiAliasingThreshold to (Number)24
5. Replace this file with preference file
6. Restart the system and Xcode

**Note:** For safer side keep backup of the original file.

Comment: Did you actually test it? It doesn't work. The text is still getting blurred by font smoothing.